# Login failed for user RPCService - C# Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, rpc

Visual Studio 2022

.Net Framework 4.7.2

I have googled this problem with no success.

When I load my windows forms solution with 17 projects I get this error
[Login Failed for user RPCService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skzqi.png)

I've narrowed it down to one form within a project. While in design time when I double click on the said form I then get this error message.

I thought maybe the form was corrupted so I recreated and copied the code and form design to the new form but error still persists.

Error also appears at run time also.

Any ideas?
Thanks
Darren

Comment: Looks like an SQL Server error, someone is trying to login with the username `RPCService`. Do you have any data connections in the project?

Comment: @Charlieface Thank for responding. No data connections.